# How can I resolve cargo build failing with "linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1"

Tags: rust

I cloned [a project](https://github.com/nushell/nushell) and ran `cargo build`. It fails with "error: linking with cc failed: exit code: 1" and something about "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:...".

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

I'm using MacOS 10.13.6 with cargo 1.40.0-nightly (5da4b4d47 2019-10-28)

EDIT: adding full error log:

```
  = note: ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
          ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
          ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//Security.framework/Security are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
          ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
          ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
          Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
            "___isOSVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
                _sectransp_connect_step1 in libcurl_sys-c02273f998a26b4c.rlib(sectransp.o)
                _sectransp_connect_step2 in libcurl_sys-c02273f998a26b4c.rlib(sectransp.o)
          ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can you tell us what symbols those are?  Those would be relevant to telling you how to fix the problem.

Comment: Add full error log. I tried with `cargo 1.41.0-nightly (8280633db 2019-11-11)` and `cargo 1.39.0 (1c6ec66d5 2019-09-30)` not getting any error.

Comment: @bk2204 added what I think is the relevant part of the error log. It was a huge output so didn't want to paste the entire thing.